# Cual es el mejor método para encriptar en php?

Tags: php, html, windows, web, encriptación

una pregunta cual es el mejor método para generar cifrados de cadenas de texto en dos sentidos? tanto para encriptar como para desencriptar, estoy hablando del año 2018, en encontrado algunas recomendaciones pero ya en años pasados. 
y si es posible algunos ejemplos para referencia.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomendaria no utilizar encriptacion en 2 vias ya que de nada sirve cifrar algo que puede ser descifrado, todo esto por cuestiones de seguridad. Si ocupas un cifrado de una sola via te recomiendo utilizar bcrypt

Comment: @Spank, creo que lo que quiere es precisamente eso, cifrar y descifrar.  A lo que te refieres es a hacer un _hash_ y no creo que sea lo que busca Carlos.

Comment: Carlos, eso depende varios factores, entre ellos la versión de php que estés usando, ya que será compatible con unas funciones que se integran en algunos métodos de cifrado y no con otras. Como ejemplo, `mcrypt_get_iv_size()` se usa en _php 5.6_, y en _php 7_ genera errores del tipo _mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated_. No obstante, pasaría por GitHub a ver las tendencias de los Frameworks, que normalmente en las últimas versiones suelen ir implementando nuevos tipos de cifrado.

Comment: Estoy ocupando PHP 7, la idea es obtener una cadena cifrada, pasandole los paramentros de contraseña y cadena, de ahí, no sé que tan posible sea ,una vez obtenida esa cadena cifrada, descifrarla mediante otro procedimiento y mostrar el valor original de la cadena.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hay que primero aprender las diferencias entre **encriptar** y el **hashing**.

El **hashing**, que es el proceso más recomendado para guardar contraseñas o información sensible en bases de datos. Genera una serie de caracteres a partir de una cadena de texto. Y solamente ocurre en una dirección, es decir, que es posible hacer esto `cadena -> hash` pero no esto `hash -> cadena`. Lo que hace imposible el proceso inverso del hash. El proceso de hashing genera una cadena de texto de un tamaño predeterminado.

El **encriptado**, convierte la información en caracteres no legibles. y la principal diferencia con el hashing es que este funciona en ambas direcciones `cadena -> encriptado` y `encriptado -> cadena` lo que permite obtener la cadena de texto original después de esta ser encriptada. La cadena de texto encriptada que se genera puede ser de un tamaño variable.

Unicamente se debe usar el encriptado si es absolutamente necesario obtener la cadena de texto original, como por ejemplo, al encriptar mensajes que se envian a otra persona.

Cuando hablamos de hashing en php, podemos usar `string password_hash ( string $password, integer $algo,array [$options])`

Donde introduciremos la contraseña, el agoritmo que usaremos, y un array de opciones que son el salt y el costo. Y obtendremos una cadena de texto con la contraseña/texto que introducimos.
Podemos utilizar los algoritmos:

- Argon2 con PASSWORD_ARGON2I (PHP 7.2, la más nueva y segura)
- Bcrypt con PASSWORD_BCRYPT

para la encripción puedes usar `base64_encode/base64_decode` (inseguro, pero una buena forma de encriptar una cadena de texto a simple vista)

También puedes usar `openssl_encrypt/openssl_decrypt` . Que es una manera mucho más segura de encriptar datos pero más complitada.

Para el proceso de encripción se debe elegir el Cifrado y modo, luego generar una llave de encriptado (que debe mantenerse en un lugar seguro y privado), un vector de inicialización que agrega aleatoriedad a la encripción. Para almacenar estos valores encriptados en Base de datos , como MySQL. Se deben usar columnas `BINARY` o `VARBINARY`